# Can't find code example of stack vs heap performance?

Tags: c#, performance

I'm working on a research paper about stack vs heap.
I have found a lot of information about the stack but not a lot about the heap?

I was searching deeply to find an example or to create an example to show performance difference between the stack and the heap.

But I have not found any code example. I
is it possible to provide some code that can show me the performance difference between the stack and the heap in c#?

Comment: C# cares nothing about stack vs heap. That's an implementation detail and largely out of your control. References types are always on the heap, and value types can be on either.

Comment: _"but not a lot about the heap"_ -  there is a whole book almost solely about "heap" by [Konrad Kokosa](https://www.amazon.com/Pro-NET-Memory-Management-Performance/dp/148424026X) (though "heap" is not fully correct term here of course, a lot of performance implications of "heap" come from GC=)

Comment: @DStanley _"references types are always on the heap"_ - I would say this is not entirely true. You can do some magic for subset of reference types with `stackalloc` =)

Comment: For the sake of argument: Let's say we could willingly use one or the other. Then what exactly do you mean by "performance"?

Comment: *"I have not found any code example"* - what exactly is stopping you from creating your own benchmarks? I'd expect a research paper to provide their own test cases to show the results of the research

Comment: Do you have any example of C# code that uses either the stack or the heap, regardless of performance? If you don't have such an example, then you should take a step back, and research first in what situations the C# uses the stack, and in what situations it uses the heap.

Comment: As others have pointed out, "stack vs. heap" is an oversimplification when it comes to where C# can store what, nor is it easy to attach performance to the use of either, certainly not in a vacuum. A research paper would be the proper medium to explore these things, but then you can't expect a simple code sample to settle the score. See also [The Stack is an Implementation Detail, Part One](https://ericlippert.com/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/) and [Part Two](https://ericlippert.com/2009/05/04/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-two/).

Comment: The most important reason for people to be obsessed with the stack vs. the heap in terms of performance is that garbage collection, while extremely convenient and a great accelerator of writing code that correctly deals with memory management, is also a considerable source of overhead in programs that eventually need to free memory. Rewriting certain memory-intensive operations in a restricted way so they only use the stack eliminates the cost of these collections, with benefits to both total runtime and latency. Of course there are trade-offs involved, which is where things get interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance difference between the two is a lot to do with implementation. The CLR is a virtual machine, which means it creates an abstraction of a computer over the actual hardware and operating system to provide a better programming experience. Therefore a lot of real things we have in our processor like register aren't visible to us.

There are a few guarantees though, for example, we know that local structs are stack allocated, and classes are heap allocated. We also know that the heap requires garbage collection and memory allocation (once the allocated data excedes a certain size to cause enough memory pressure for the CLR to allocate a new segment) whereas the stack is pre-allocated per thread. Does this give us a performance difference? It depends how you develop, a lot of times using stack allocated structs can make your program slower, eg by passing data by value which requires expensive copies rather than passing a single reference. For an example of a performance difference see this:

```cs
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Columns;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Configs;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Diagnosers;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Loggers;

namespace StackVsHeap
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RunBenchmarks();
        }

        public static void RunBenchmarks()
        {
            var config = new ManualConfig()
                .AddLogger(ConsoleLogger.Default)
                .AddColumn(TargetMethodColumn.Method, StatisticColumn.Median, StatisticColumn.StdDev,
                    StatisticColumn.Q1, StatisticColumn.Q3, new ParamColumn("Size"));
            BenchmarkDotNet.Running.BenchmarkRunner.Run<ExampleBenchmark>(config);

        }
    }

    [ShortRunJob]
    public class ExampleBenchmark
    {
        [Benchmark]
        public void BenchmarkHeap()
        {
            long y = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                var x = new TestClass(1,2,3,4);
                y=y&x.CalculateXor();
            }
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public unsafe void BenchmarkStack()
        {
            long y = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                var x = new TestStruct(1, 2, 3, 4);
                y = y & x.CalculateXor();
            }
        }
    }

    public record TestClass(long a, long b, long c, long d)
    {
        public long CalculateXor()
        {
            return a ^ b ^ c ^ d;
        }
    }
    public record struct TestStruct(long a, long b, long c, long d)
    {
        public long CalculateXor()
        {
            return a ^ b ^ c ^ d;
        }
    }

}
```

The stack allocated example requires 0 heap allocations and is all performed in the thread stack which is allocated on startup. Therefore there is almost no allocation cost and also no object header. In addition the memory allocated for the `TestStruct` is freed as soon as the loop is exited by simply decrementing the stack pointer, whereas for the `TestClass` it will only be freed through GC, so int he stack example you're continually hitting the same address which is far more likely to be in the CPU cache.

Here is the result of the above benchmark measured with Benchmark.NET:

```
|         Method |   StdDev |    Median |        Q1 |        Q3 |
|--------------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|
|  BenchmarkHeap | 5.947 us | 342.12 us | 338.34 us | 344.20 us |
| BenchmarkStack | 0.028 us |  20.79 us |  20.77 us |  20.80 us |
```

This is a roughly 15x difference.

Comment: thanks a lot !!! this is exactly what i was looking for. I'm fairly new to performance and memory management. But this code made it clear for me